# How to make the code compliant with: Move this variable to comply with Java Code Conventions

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have the following class:

```java
public final class AppConst {
    private AppConst() {}
        
    public static final String READ_ERROR = "READ";
    public static final String PROCESS_ERROR = "PROCESS";
    public static final String WRITE_ERROR = "WRITE";
}
```

SonarQube marks errors on all three lines with the variables:

> Move this variable to comply with Java Code Conventions.

How to make the code compliant with SonarQube?

I'm using SonarLint for Eclipse v2.6.0.

Comment: The was no question in the post, so I added it. I hope this is the question which you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is found by the [RSPEC-1213 The members of an interface or class declaration should appear in a pre-defined order](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1213) rule. The description says:

> According to the Java Code Conventions as defined by Oracle, the members of a class or interface declaration should appear in the following order in the source files:
>
> - Class and instance variables
> - Constructors
> - Methods

Your code contains a constructor before the variables. Valid code:

```java
public final class AppConst {   
    public static final String READ_ERROR = "READ";
    public static final String PROCESS_ERROR = "PROCESS";
    public static final String WRITE_ERROR = "WRITE";

    private AppConst() {}
}
```